# How to Create a Python Program that searches for a value in a NumPy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a Python Dictionary that I converted to a NumPy array. I did this because I have some keys that show up multiple times in the dictionary (the 'Red Velvet' cupcake specifically). I'm having difficulty figuring out how to create a program that outputs a value based on a specific key inputed.

My Python Dictionary looks like this:

```
cupcake_dict =
   {'Red Velvet': 'Princess Cupcakes',
    'Vanilla': 'Vanilla Patisserie',
    'Chocolate': 'Beary Good Cupcakes',
    'Red Velvet': 'Bonjour Bakery'
   }
```

So, first I converted my Python Dictionary (cupcake_dict) to an array:

```
result = cupcake_dict.items()
result_list = list(result)
cupcake_array = np.array(result_list)
```

Now, using this array, I am trying to create the program that takes an input (a key in the Python Dictionary) and searches the array (cupcake_array) to output the value (shop location). I want the program to output all the possible values. For instance, for the red velvet cupcake, there are two locations it is available at. I'm trying to get the program to print both locations for these keys.

I am struggling with, first, outputting a value from the array, and, second, outputting more than one value from the array if applicable.

Here is what I have so far (not correct):

```
cake_name = input("Enter Cupcake Type: ")
if cake_name in cupcake_array:
  print("Cupcake Type: " + cake_name)
  print("Cupcake Location: " + cupcake_array.index(cake_name))
else:
  print("Cupcake not available at any locations")
```

Where am I going wrong? Am I approaching this correctly? Thank you!

Comment: Dictionaries cannot have duplicated keys. If you have the same key twice in the same dictionary the last one with be the only one. For example, `cupcake_dict == {'Red Velvet': 'Bounjour Bakery', 'Vanilla': "Vanilla Patisserie', 'Chocolate': 'Beary Good Cupcakes' }`. As a result your numpy array will not include the `'Princess Cupcakes` value that you might be expecting. You probably just want your `cupcake_dict` to map a flavor to a name: `{'Red Velvet': ['Princess Cupcakes', 'Bonjour Bakery']}`

Comment: How could I approach this then instead to output all values, if not through a dictionary or an array?

Comment: Just store a list of cupcake names with each flavor instead: `{'Red Velvet': ['Princess Cupcakes', 'Bonjour Bakery'], 'Vanilla': ['Vanilla Pattisserie'], 'Chocolate': ['Beary Good Cupcakes']}`